# Mysql: Duplicate and incorrect output when using join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 4 tables on which I need to use a join. The query is returning duplicate rows. However for simplicity I will post my question with just 2 tables as the problem still exits even with 2 tables. Tables are called as product_offer and promo. The structures are as below

```
product_offer table:
id  product_id   offer_id   store_id   validity
1     1            1          1       2016-12-12 00:00:00

2     2            2          1       2016-12-12 00:00:00

3     3            3          1       2016-12-12 00:00:00

4     1            4          1       2016-12-12 00:00:00
```

```
promo table:
id  product_id   store_id      name                       
1     1            1          Buy 1 Get 1 free       

2     2            1          10% off       

3     3            1          $10 off       

4     1            1          Get Chips Free
```

I am trying to fetch all the offers for a particular product-store combination. I am expecting to get this

```
product_id offer_id  store_id     name
1            1         1       Buy 1 Get 1 Free
1            4         1       Get Chips Free
```

But When I run this query I am getting the below output which is incorrect and with duplicate rows

```
    SELECT po.product_id, po.offer_id,po.store_id,o.name
    from product_offer po
    left join promo o on po.product_id = o.product_id
    where po.product_id  = 1 and po.store_id = 1
```

```
product_id offer_id  store_id     name
1            1         1       Buy 1 Get 1 Free
1            4         1       Buy 1 Get 1 Free 
1            1         1       Get Chips Free
1            4         1       Get Chips Free
```

I also want to improve the query and use concat(using ~ as separator) to only return one row per product_id as below:

```
product_id offer_id  store_id  name
1           1~4        1       Buy 1 Get 1 free~Get Chips Free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was doing the Join ON the wrong column. When I changed the join on offer_id from product_offer and id on promo it worked nicely.

```
SELECT     po.product_id,  group_concat(po.offer_id SEPARATOR '~') offer_id, po.store_id ,group_concat(o.name SEPARATOR '~') offer
FROM product_offer po
        LEFT JOIN
    promo o ON po.offer_id = o.id
WHERE
    po.product_id = 1 and po.store_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Group by` with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT po.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT po.offer_id SEPARATOR '~') offer_id
,po.store_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.name SEPARATOR '~') name
from product_offer po
left join promo o on po.product_id = o.product_id
where po.product_id  = 1 and po.store_id = 1
Group by product_id
```

Comment: That is not working as it gives me only one row  without using group_concat and with group_concat it gives me both the offers repeated twice as in Buy 1 Get 1 free~Get Chips Free~Buy 1 Get 1 free~Get Chips Free

Comment: SELECT po.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT po.offer_id SEPARATOR '~') offer_id
,po.store_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.name SEPARATOR '~') name
from product_offer po
left join promo o on po.product_id = o.product_id
where po.product_id  = 1 and po.store_id = 1
Group by product_id

Comment: this works. But any idea why the query I used is giving duplicate and incorrect rows?

Comment: i think left join create duplicate rows @FBP

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a GROUP BY, what does it, it takes the column you chose  puts them together to avoid duplicate results where data in that column matches

```
SELECT po.product_id, po.offer_id,po.store_id,o.name
    from product_offer po
    left join promo o on po.product_id = o.product_id
    where po.product_id  = 1 and po.store_id = 1
    GROUP BY product_id
```

In order to concatenate them, there is the option of GROUP_CONCAT, you can read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to group by offer_id

`SELECT po.product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(po.offer_id SEPARATOR '~') offer_id,po.store_id,o.name
from product_offer po
left join promo o on po.product_id = o.product_id
where po.product_id  = 1 and po.store_id = 1
Group by offer_id`

Comment: This is not working as it returns 2 rows but the name Buy 1 Get 1 free is repeated in both rows.